# filter csv file based on list of id in another file

Tags: linux, awk, csv

I have a large csv file with these format
file 1:

```
id,ICD,CT
16214497,008.8,1
16227244,401.1,45
27154870,780.79,1
```

I have another txt file with one column of list of id (header id).
file 2:

```
id
16214497
27154870
```

I want another file that has only data limited to the list of id in file 2

output file:

```
id,ICD,CT
16214497,008.8,1
27154870,780.79,1
```

Answer (score 2):

If the files have the common lines in the same order,

```
join -t, -j1 file1.txt file2.txt
```

### Explanation

See `man join` for more information. Basically, `join` the two files, skipping "unpairable lines". The delimiter is a comma `-t,`, and join on field 1 `-j1`.

Comment: the file 1 is large csv file and is not sorted. file 2 is just list of ids not the total line.

Comment: @motor30 Please add this information to the question. Is it okay to reorder the files, i.e. `join -t, -j1 <(sort file1.txt) <(sort file2.txt)`?

Comment: it only give empty file bash-4.2$ join -t, -j1 <(sort file1.txt) <(sort file2.txt)> 3.csv          please note that the file 1 is a csv file "file1.csv", I just change it to txt but the same

Comment: @motor30 Sorry I don't totally understand. In my commands, `file1.txt` and `file2.txt` are just dummy file names. You should replace them with the actual names of your files.

Answer (score 1):

Using `csvjoin` from the Python-based [csvkit](https://csvkit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/cli.html)

```
$ csvjoin -Ic id file\ 1 file\ 2
id,ICD,CT
16214497,008.8,1
27154870,780.79,1
```

The `-I` flag disables type inference so that fields like `008.8` are treated as strings rather than as numerics (which may cause re-formating). This method appears to handle DOS/Windows style line endings transparently.

---

Alternative quick'n'dirty join using awk:

```
awk -F, 'NR==FNR {a[$1]; next} $1 in a' file\ 2 file\ 1
```

If your file has DOS/Windows line endings (CRLF in place of plain LF) then you can try

```
awk -vRS='\r\n' -F, 'NR==FNR {a[$1]; next} $1 in a' file\ 2 file\ 1
```

or convert your file first using `dos2unix`, `tr`, `sed` etc.

Comment: I am working on Linux and it doesn't seem to have this option...I was hoping for awk or grep

Comment: @motor30 many Linuxes package `csvkit` now I think (it's certainly available on Debian based systems) however I've added a suggestion with awk

Comment: awk -F, 'NR==FNR {a[$1]; next} $1 in a' file2.csv file1.csv > 2.csv
             somehow it only make an empty csv file

Comment: @motor30 do your CSV files have Windows line endings (CRLF rather than plain LF)? if so, try adding `-vRS='\r\n'` to the awk options

Comment: could you please re-write the complete line, thanks

Comment: ok...this option  finally solved the issue   bash-4.2$ cat file2.csv | tr -d '\015' > myfile3.csv

Answer (score 0):

With `grep` and `sed`:

You could add a `^` to the beginning of each line and a `,` to the end of each line of file2 and use `grep`:

```
grep -f <(sed 's/^/^/;s/$/,/' file2) file1
```

Option `-f` reads the patterns from a file (in our example not from a real file, but from a process substitution `<(…)`).