# select rows based on another file

Tags: awk, grep

I have a large file: (file1.csv)

```
id,code,N
10214411,008.8,1
10214411,038.9,1
10214411,04.81,1
10214411,07.22,1
```

want to select and generate a new file based on second column with a list of IDs e.g:

second file has a large list of IDs for second column such as:(file2.csv):

```
0.008.8
07.22
```

result:(file3.csv)

```
id,code,N
10214411,008.8,1
10214411,07.22,1
```

Comment: Is the first entry of the second file really `0.008.8` - or is it `008.8`? if the former, what are the rules for approximate matches?

Comment: "large" is relative. How many rows and columns are typical in each file?

Comment: Also - this is exactly the same as your previous question (https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/548429/133219) but using $2 from file1.csv instead of $1. Why do you need to ask it again?

Comment: It seems that a single grep could do the job like `grep -F -f file2.csv file1.cvs`. You just need to workaround the preservation of the header row of file1. Grep is expected to be super fast in large files.

Comment: @GeorgeVasiliou the problems with a grep solution are 1) it cant target specific fields (so a number from file2 that occurs in field3 of file1 would erroneously match when it should only match if it appears in file1 field 2) and 2) POSIX grep at least can't target specific "words" (so 5.3 in file 2 would match 15.37 in file1 filed 2). The result is that you could get a lot more output than is desireable.

Answer (score 3):

Like this, using `bash` shell, `paste` and `awk` :

### Input file

```
$ cat file2.csv
008.8
07.22
```

### Code

Crafting a regex from a little hack in a shell variable :

```
re="^($(paste -sd '|' file2.csv))$"
```

...now, `$re` variable contains the regex `^(008.8|07.22)$`

Then, passing re as variable to awk :
( `${re//./\\.}` is a bash parameter expansion to backslash dots => `^(008\.8|07\.22)$` )

```
awk -F, -v re="${re//./\\.}" 'NR==1 || $2 ~ re' file1.csv | tee file3.csv
```

### Output

```
$ cat file3.csv
id,code,N
10214411,008.8,1
10214411,07.22,1
```

---

## Another solution

(not tested)

```
{ 
    echo 'id,code,N'
    while IFS=, read -r _ id __; do
        awk -F, -v id=$id '$2==id' file1.csv
    done < file2.csv 
} | tee -a file3.csv
```

Comment: the second file has a large list of IDs from a file

Comment: POST edited accordingly

Comment: i have two file: file1.csv, file2.csv     i am not sure what you wrote above

Comment: Is the file of list of ID is comma `,` separated ?

Comment: the list of ID in second file is just one single large column as shown above,

Comment: OK, I just edited the file names, the code works, test it

Comment: this what i have and is not working $ cat file1.csv
re="($(paste -sd '|' file1.csv))" 
awk -F, -vre=$re 'NR==1 || $2 ~ re' file2.csv > file3.csv

Comment: Add this to your original POST, it's not readable as comment. Take care as my fisrt id from file1.csv is not exactly the same as you, don't know if it's a typo from you or not

Comment: Just inverted file1 and file 2, maybe you would guess before ? :)

Comment: not working,  also how the result in second command line,  in regard to  file2,  connect to third command line for file3??

Comment: @motor30 With first line of `file2.csv` corrected to `008.8`, I just tested it and it works. With first line as provided, i.e. `0.008.8` it still _works_, but that line is not reported because it's not a match.

Comment: the file2.csv has a large list of ids. not just 2.  also how the second commad line give input for  the third command line?

Comment: The second command line create the third file using `tee`. The snippet is suited for any record id in file2.csv (limited by RAM)

Comment: please provide alternative. it doesnt provide any response after 30 min

Comment: Maybe try with a smaller set to test and if you want to do the whole and ensure there's nothings hangs, use `strace -ff -s 1000 awk <command>`

Comment: Added another solution

Comment: That final script would read the whole of file1.csv 10,000 times if file2.csv was 10,000 lines long which may not be great for speed of execution. It'd also change the order of output from the order in file1 to the order in file2 but that may not matter and the questions not clear on which file the output order is based on anyway.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming the `0.008.8` in file2.csv in your question is a typo and it should be `008.8` instead, it seems like this is what you want:

```
awk -F, 'NR==FNR{a[$1]; next} FNR==1 || $2 in a' file2.csv file1.csv > file3.csv
```

e.g.:

```
$ awk -F, 'NR==FNR{a[$1]; next} FNR==1 || $2 in a' file2.csv file1.csv
id,code,N
10214411,008.8,1
10214411,07.22,1
```

Comment: this only print the first line of file1.csv into file3.csv.

Comment: @motor30 that makes no sense. This solution should work fluently and fast. PS: Are you working under Windows maybe ....?

Comment: @motor30 As George suggests you almost certainly have the problem discussed at https://stackoverflow.com/q/45772525/1745001. If you don't have that problem then either your input files don't look like you've told us they do or you aren't copy/pasting the script correctly.

Comment: thank you...the file 2 need a dos2unix  chnage and after i did the  command:    cat file2.csv | tr -d '\015' > file2b.csv       now it is working

Comment: You're welcome. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers for what to do next.

Comment: @EdMorton Would it be a "bad" practice to adjust `RS` & `ORS` into `CRLF` ...?

Comment: @GeorgeVasiliou yes you can do that, it just makes the code gawk-specific due to multi-char RS.

Answer (score 0):

`head` and `grep` will work together for this job: `grep -F` so grep treats the lines in file2 as fixed strings not regular expressions.

```bsh
{
  head -n 1 file1.csv
  grep -F -f file2.csv file1.csv
}
```

```
id,code,N
10214411,008.8,1
10214411,07.22,1
```

I'm using the braces here so it's easier to redirect the output of both commands at once:

```bsh
{ cmd1; cmd2; ...; } > output.txt
```